How can I reuse a boost::asio socket, received from acceptor.async_accept call in coroutine environement?
I'm new to Boost::Asio and have encountered a problem with asio::ip::tcp::socket storage. I receive a server side socket from an asio::ip::tcp::acceptor.async_accept() call and store it in allocated memory. Then, when I initiate the socket.async_send() call, nothing happens: no action, no errors. If the socket is in global memory everything works fine. What should I do? Here is my (pseudo) code:
// Connecting coro
asio::awaitable<void> run_server(asio::io_context &context) // contex is globally allocated
{
        asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(context, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{asio::ip::make_address_v4(p_joinserver->get_ip_addr()), p_joinserver->get_port()});
        while (true)
        {
// Preliminary create a soket and place it into unordered map            
auto psocket = std::make_shared<socket_t>(context);
            auto handle = std::rand();
            auto [iter, res] = p_server->connections.emplace(std::make_pair(handle,psocket)); 

            *psocket = co_await acceptor.async_accept(asio::use_awaitable); // Works OK

            asio::co_spawn(context, read_requests(handle), asio::detached);
        }
}

// Receiving and sending coro
asio::awaitable<void> read_requests(int handle)
{

    constexpr size_t buf_size = 1024;
    std::string line(buf_size, '\0');


        while (true)
        {
            auto psocket = p_server->connections.at(handle);
  
            auto n_read = co_await psocket->async_read_some(
                asio::buffer(line),
                asio::use_awaitable); // Works OK
// <> 
//..prepare sending
            auto _psocket = p_server->connections.at(handle);
            auto n_sent = co_await _psocket->async_send(
                 asio::buffer(line),
                 asio::use_awaitable); // Does nothing and throw no error 
    }
}



I am very grateful to @stephen for the useful approch, he suggested,
but he did not answer the main question, which I may have phrased inaccurately:
How one can keep sockets, initialised with different connections for use in coroutines to be called later?
The working answer: I should have used another form of async_accept, for example:
`p_connection = std::make_shared<connection_t>(context /*,<constructor args>*/); co_await acceptor.async_accept(p_connection->socket, asio::use_awaitable);`


The beauty of coroutines is that they can accept actual arguments. I’d just write:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

// Receiving and sending coro
asio::awaitable<void> read_requests(tcp::socket s) 
{
  constexpr size_t buf_size = 1024;
  std::string line(buf_size, '\0');

  while (true)
  {
    auto n_read = co_await s.async_read_some(
        asio::buffer(line),
        asio::use_awaitable); // Works OK
    // <> 
    //..prepare sending
    auto n_sent = co_await s.async_send(
          asio::buffer(line, n_read),
          asio::use_awaitable); // Does nothing and throw no error 
  }
}

// Connecting coro
struct Config {
  std::string get_ip_addr() const { return "127.0.0.1"; }
  uint16_t get_port() const { return 8989; }
};

asio::awaitable<void> run_server(Config const* p_joinserver) 
{
  auto executor = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
  tcp::endpoint ep{
     asio::ip::make_address_v4(p_joinserver->get_ip_addr()),
     p_joinserver->get_port()};

  tcp::acceptor acceptor(executor, ep);
  while (true) {
      auto socket = co_await acceptor.async_accept(asio::use_awaitable); // Works OK
      asio::co_spawn(executor, read_requests(std::move(socket)), asio::detached);
  }
}

int main() {
  Config const cfg;
  asio::io_context ioc;
  co_spawn(ioc, run_server(&cfg), asio::detached);
  ioc.run_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
}

If you insist that the server must also maintain a list of connections, my preferred mechanism is shared pointers to a session object. In that case, read_requests should be a member function of the session object.
A far better handle will be the weak_ptr to that session, because it not only is guaranteed to be unique, it’s also inherently always pointing to the corresponding session object instance (unless it has terminated, which can be asynchronous).
You can see loads of answers on this site demonstrating that with e.g.
std::list<std::weak_ptr<Session> > sessions_;

Or, more idiomatically:
using Handle = std::weak_ptr<Session>;
std::list<Handle> sessions_;

This will allow the server to garbage collect expired sessions (those that closed e.g. due to network error/peer disconnect):
sessions_.remove_if(&Handle::expired);


Hi sehe, thank you for sharing your experience, - I will implement a collection of weak_ptr-s to sessions - but my question rests unaswered:
what is wrong with storing the sockets my way? So it was intended that the assignment operator transmits only a part of the socket state?
